# paint brush illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

In illustrator paintbrush creates extra black spot/patch in a curly path. How can I get rid of this?

I have set the stroke corner limit to zero. Still no result. Please help.[image]

Comment: Disable gpu acceleration first

Comment: I have no option like this under 'graphic settings'

Comment: It's under *Preferences > Performance > GPU Performance*.

Comment: oh! I thought it was to be the System's “Hardware-accelerated GPU'' .Thank you @wolff.

Comment: How zoomed in are you? I've seen this happen when drawing too small.